# sort numbers which has odd-index in vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, console-application, windows

I want to sort numbers in vector which has odd-index (index starts from `0`).

For example, if I enter this numbers; `1 6 5 7 3 2 0`, program must returns this: `1 2 5 6 3 7 0`.

My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int eded, n, _temp;
    size_t i;

    cout << "Nece eded daxil edeceksiniz?" << endl << ">>> ";
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> v_eded;
    v_eded.reserve(n); // n qeder bosh yer ayiriram vektor-da

    cout << "Ededleri daxil edin:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> eded;
        v_eded.push_back(eded);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < v_eded.size(); i+=2)
    {
        if (v_eded[i] > v_eded[i+2])
        {
            _temp = v_eded[i+2];
            v_eded[i+2] = v_eded[i];
            v_eded[i] = _temp;
        }
    }

    for (auto j : v_eded)
        cout << j << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without any warning and/or error. After inserting `eded`, I'm pressing `Enter` and program gives me this error:

[image]

I couldn't determine what's the problem. Please, explain me what's the wrong and how to solve this.

Best regards.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "I want to sort numbers in vector which has odd-index (index starts from 0)." However the error you see is because you access an index that is out of bounds for your vector

Comment: press retry to debug. (The break should be at `if (v_eded[i] > v_eded[i+2])`).

Comment: A nice thing about C++ is all the nice [algorithm functions in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example functions [to partition a range into two parts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition), and then let you [sort any part of the range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev : Sorry for bad english. I gave an example in my post.

Comment: @Jarod42 unfortunately I have never used debugger. :(

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'll read it.

Comment: @coni - Why didn't you do as the dialog stated "Press Retry to debug"???  It would have taken you to the line that caused the error.  If not that line, the call stack will show you the line in your code that led to the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : thanks for attention. I know it. I pressed it before. but what's the next step?

Comment: @coni The debugger should have taken you to the line that is causing the issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I clicked the `Debug` button, and it took me to the  line that is causing the issue. 

`if (v_eded[i] > v_eded[i+2])` this line caused the problem. I understand. So, bottom of the compiler a little window opened. In this window variables have some values. 

So, how to solve the problem with these *values*?

Comment: @coni Those values are the values of those variables when the crash occurs.  You do see that the expression is out of bounds (the `i + 2`).  Also, you wrote the program -- you should know what each line is *supposed* to do since you had a plan in mind.  You see that the index went to far, correct?  So I don't know the difficulty of (at the very least) telling us that you know what the problem is, even if you don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks. I actually understand what's the cause of problem. But I don't know how to fix it. :/

Comment: @coni - You're supposed to plan everything before you write the code and be prepared to either adjust the (non-working) code to fit your plan, or go back and rethink/redo your plan.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for everything. I should adjust my code. I think there is no problem with plan.

Answer (score 1):

You have out of bound access with

```
if (v_eded[i] > v_eded[i+2])
```

where only `i < v_eded.size()`, not `i + 2`

Answer (score 1):

this should more or less do it:

```
    #include <boost/iterator_adaptors.hpp>

    using namespace std;

    template<class Iter>
    struct by_2_iterator
    : boost::iterator_adaptor<by_2_iterator<Iter>, Iter>
    {
        by_2_iterator(Iter it, Iter limit)
        : by_2_iterator::iterator_adaptor_(it)
        , _limit(limit)
        {}

    private:

        struct enabler {};  // a private type avoids misuse
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

        void advance(typename by_2_iterator<Iter>::difference_type n)
        {
            std::advance(this->base_reference(), n * 2);
        }

        void increment()
        {
            auto dist = _limit - this->base_reference();
            if (dist == 1) {
                ++(this->base_reference());
                _was_half = true;
            }
            else {
                this->advance(1);
                _was_half = false;
            }
        }

        void decrement()
        {
            if (_was_half) {
                --(this->base_reference());
                _was_half = false;
            }
            else {
                this->advance(-1);
            }
        }

    private:
        Iter _limit;
        bool _was_half = false;
    };

    template<class Iter>
    by_2_iterator<Iter>
    make_by_2(Iter it, Iter e) {
        return by_2_iterator<Iter>(it, e);
    }


    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(play_2sort)
    {

        std::vector<int> v { 1, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 0 };

        auto b = make_by_2(begin(v)+1, end(v));
        auto e = make_by_2(end(v), end(v));

        std::sort(b, e);

        std::copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
        cout << endl;



    }
```

Comment: thanks for attention. But, I don't have knowledge at this *level*. So, I don't know how to use these codes for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited my code and I used simple `*select sort*` algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int eded, n, _temp, min_i;
    size_t i, j;

    cout << "Nece eded daxil edeceksiniz?" << endl << ">>> ";
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> v_eded;
    v_eded.reserve(n); // n qeder bosh yer ayiriram vektor-da

    cout << "Ededleri daxil edin:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> eded;
        v_eded.push_back(eded);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) // or you can replace " n " with v_eded.size()
    {
        min_i = i;
        for (j = i; j < n; j += 2)
        {
            if (v_eded[j] < v_eded[min_i])
                min_i = j;

            _temp = v_eded[i];
            v_eded[i] = v_eded[min_i];
            v_eded[min_i] = _temp;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    for (auto v : v_eded)
        cout << v << "  ";

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.